# How can I find an <acronym> tag with watir-webdriver without taking a huge performance hit?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver (0.5.3) in a Cucumber (1.1.9) test.  I am attempting to verify the text value of an `<acronym>` tag.  The code is legacy, and there are plans to change it to a `<div>` or `<span>` tag, but in the mean time I have to deal with it.  I first attempted:

```rb
@browser.acronym(:id => /expense_code(.*)/).text
```

I received the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `acronym' for #<Watir::Browser:0x33e9940>
```

I poked around in the Watir code to see how tag objects were being created, and found that they seem to be dynamically created based on the HTML5 spec, but then I also found a comment in `element.rb` stating that they are no longer being created from the spec.  At any rate, I couldn't see an easy way to inherit a `<span>` object and call it an `<acronym>` object.  So, I looked into alternatives, and found the element object.

```rb
@browser.element(:id => /expense_code(.*)/).text
```

This code works, but it takes about a minute to traverse my page.  I'm stuck with the regex for now, as the tag id is actually dynamically generated and I don't currently have a way to figure out those values.  This is what the tag actually looks like:

```html
<acronym class="editable select fillwith:exp_codes default:E100"
title="Expense Code: Expenses" id="expense_code114_582_10777">
E100    </acronym>
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on how I can improve the performance of my test.

Comment: FYI: in terms of updating your legacy code, the recommended HTML5 replacement is to use the abbr tag (not to be confused with the abba tag which would be a Swedish variant on a rickroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is here, but this is the answer I came up with using Chuck's reply and feedback from jarib in the #watir IRC chat.  With all my examples, `expense_code = 'E100'`.

```rb
@browser.element(:tag_name => "acronym", 
                    :class => "default:#{expense_code}").text
```

The above code works at a very reasonable speed and doesn't require an xpath.  It is a shortening of the following code:

```rb
@browser.element(:tag_name => "acronym", 
     :class => "editable select fillwith:exp_codes default:#{expense_code}").text
```

I learned that I didn't need to pass the whole string.  Anything in a class delimited by a space is dealt with gracefully by watir.  I adapted that code from this xpath:

```rb
@browser.element(:xpath => "//acronym[contains(@class,
    \'editable select fillwith:exp_codes default:#{expense_code}\')]").text
```

The gotcha in that code above was needing to escape out the `'` around the class values so that it would evaluate correctly.

Just searching for the class (code below) did not work.  I have no idea why.  I did notice that it pounded the database with requests.  Whatever it was doing, the page didn't like it.  Though the reason it was trying multiple times is I slipped a `wait_until_present` in there.

```rb
@browser.element(:class, "editable select fillwith:exp_codes
    default:#{expense_code}").text
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did the performance of this solution compare to your original solution?

Comment: It went from about 1:30 to ~:35 +/- 5 seconds.  I had two other regexes in there, and when I removed them, I got it down to ~25 seconds.

Comment: etiquette wise, I think it's fine to post your own answer and give credit as you did.  I'd also upvote each of the responses that lead to you coming up with a solution.  it''s not quite as much rep as the green checkmark, but it adds up and is a pretty decent 'consolation prize' as it were.

Comment: I did upvote everyone who helped me, which in this case was everyone who posted. :)  Thanks.  I don't want to step on toes.

Answer (score 4):

Does using XPath to limit the elements to just acronym tags help performance?

```
@browser.element(:xpath, "//acronym[contains(@id, 'expense_code')]")
```

UPDATE: As Chuck mentioned, CSS-Selector is also an option:

```
@browser.element(:css => "acronym[id^=expense_code]")
```

Comment: You might be able to do something similar using a CSS selector as well.  not sure if it would be faster, but could be worth a try

Comment: I didn't try a CSS selector, but I did try limiting to //acronym and it couldn't find it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Is that class name predictable?  could you construct that from a set part plus the text you are about to validate (it's the same in your example above) and go that way?

```
acronym = 'E100'
browser.element(:class, 'editable select fillwith:exp_codes default:#{acronym}'.text.should == acronym
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck.  I fiddled with this, and using your suggestion and with some help from jarib in the #watir IRC chat.  I was able to use the following to solve my problem:

    @browser.element(:tag_name => "acronym", :class => "default:#{expense_code}").text

Comment: Awsome, that looks like it borrows a bit from what Justin suggested (using :tag_name as a locator)  and what I suggested re the class name.   Love it when a solution comes together out of multiple answers. (although that makes it hard for you to pick just one to tick as an accepted answer)  A bit strange that the partial class name worked without having to use a regex there, but if it works, run with it!

Comment: Yeah, the site developers said using the class was better than the id, as they want to get rid of the ids at some point.  However I still started down the path of constructing them from the DB, because that allows me to create a unique id that I know is good (until they remove them.)

Comment: Sounds like it might be time to have a talk with them about testability, and making it easy to identify ui elements in a predictable way.  which is typically via either id, name, or class

Comment: The plan is to use class names.  They just haven't gotten all the legacy code updated yet.  Now that I know I can cherry-pick classes delimted by spaces, it'll be a lot easier I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently stealing logic from Watir 1.6.5 to make custom locators/collections for my page objects and I noticed in the Watir::TaggedElementLocator, it kind of supports any method that the element supports. Noticing in Watir-Webdriver that elements have a tag_name() method, I thought I would try the same and it looks like it works.

So you can use tag_name as a locator by doing:

```
@browser.element(:tag_name => 'acronym', :id => /expense_code(.*)/).text
```

I'm not sure what order the locators get run in, so since the regex is expensive, it might be faster to get all the acronym elements and then find the one with the right ID:

```
@browser.elements(:tag_name, 'acronym').find{ |acronym|
  acronym.id =~ /expense_code(.*)/ 
}.text
```

While I think it makes the code look better, unfortunately I'm not sure if its any faster. I am guessing the performance of each will depend on the specific page layout being tested.

Comment: some good thoughts here, looks like using :tag_name as a selector worked into his eventual solution.

Comment: Thanks Justin.  I actually did try the tag name, and had issues with it, but I think that was when I was attempting to pretend it was a span to see if that would work.  As Chuck pointed out, I did end up using it in the end.