# watir, element not currently visible

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to interact with a widget on a webpage, enter data into a form element.  But I'm getting an error saying the elements isn't currently visible so cannot be interacted with.  When manually interacting with the page, the text box asks you to enter something, then that text goes away when you click on the box and accepts input.   I've tried having watir click the box first but that isn't working for me either.  Here is the raw html:

```
<input class="symbol-search ui-autocomplete-input x-defaulttext-ghost" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">`
```

after I click on the box in my browser that changes to this:

```
<input class="symbol-search ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">`
```

Suggestions?   Not possible?

Comment: Show us the watircode you were trying to use when you got that error.

Comment: Can you do this action manually?  I had the same problem and it turned out that the element just wasn't visible like I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem is that the input element in your code lacks a 'type' attribute, which is what watir uses to distinguish things like text_field from checkbox (since they are all input elements, but act differently)

Without that type attribute (role doesn't really cut it, it's not even a standard element for an input field, not even in html5, [not as far as I can tell](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_input.asp)

Lacking a type attribute, you won't be able to use most of the standard input types supported by watir, which means you won't have access to a .set method  You are likely going to have to address this with the basic 'element' class, and then use something like .send_keys once it has been clicked in order to fire keystrokes at it.

Who's widget is this anyway? do they have a demo page that shows an example of it?  that would make it easier for people to discover potential ways to work with the control.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
b.text_field(:class => /autocomplete/).set 'hello'
```

Comment: I've used that in a number of my tests, and I notice it tends to slow down performance of my tests.  In one case I removed three regexes in three elements (one for each) from a script, and I shaved 20 seconds off the run time of that scenario.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use the full class name as long as it's consistent.  Most of the supported attributes (http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir <- this is mostly right) are not part of your html.

Comment: I dealt with it by using a partial class name combined with a tag name.  I discussed how I got there in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093114/how-can-i-find-an-acronym-tag-with-watir-webdriver-without-taking-a-huge-perfo